# Errors in Parameterized Logging in java using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I recently started using Log4j. I came across a better logging technique of parameterized logging.

I referred the below link.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html

The above link is for log4j2. But I was wondering if the same is applicable for 1.2.9

When I try to write a logger statement with parameters, I am getting below error.

> The method info(Object, Throwable) in the type Category is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, String)

I checked the source code of

I am using log4j 1.2.9

The java code is as below.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.test.validators.CreateValidator;

public class CreateLogic {

    Logger admin = Logger.getLogger("admin");

public void createLogic(){
    admin.info("This is Create Logic");
    CreateValidator CreateValidator = new CreateValidator();
    CreateValidator.validateCreate();
    int i = 5;
    admin.info("the name is {}",i);

    }

}
```

log4j properties are as below.

```
log4j.logger.admin=INFO, admin
log4j.additivity.admin = false

log4j.appender.admin=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.admin.File=C:\\Create.log
log4j.appender.admin.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.admin.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.admin.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.admin.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Comment: You're right. `.info(Object message, Throwable t)` is offered in both 1.x and 2.x APIs. You're issue seems to be that you're passing in `i` as a Throwable, but it's not.

Comment: how do I write parameterized loggers in that case?

Comment: I see the issue

Comment: Hey, just curious on how you resolved the issue, if you did.

Comment: I upgraded to log4j 2. Use it along with slf4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that you reference from the 2.x API *isn't* parameterized logging, or at least in the way you want. The method that you actually want is [void info(String message, Object... params)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html)) . And this method is a part of the log4j 2.x API. It looks like log4j 1.x doesn't offer it on its own. However, if you *aren't* bound to log4j, you could take a look at the sl4j library, which essentially hides the log4j implementation and offers that parameterized logging functionality.

If you *are* bound to log4j, then I think one solution would be to format the message beforehand with the parameters you would have passed in the log message, like so:

```
 int i = 5;
 String msg = String.format("the name is %d", i);
 admin.info(msg);
```

Hope that helps.